# Get all pixel information of an image efficiently

Tags: c#

I made a program to get all image pixel RGB color codes from picture. Basically, it sets y position on constant and changes x position zero to width and also y by looping.

Ok it's work, but the problem is it take more than 20 minutes to get all pixel from even (1000*604 height width) image. Please anyone help?

I'm surprised if this process takes so long, then how can we make a program like bar-code reader from image. I want to get all pixel value from image, here is my C# code are below.

I also uploaded my program [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?7etr90i4hqkoa2q), check it if you don't agree.

```
    void myimage() {

        mypic = new Bitmap(pathname);
        int imwid = mypic.Width;
        int imhei = mypic.Height;
        int total=imwid*imhei;

        for (int z = 0; z <imhei;z++ )
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < imwid; i++)
            {
                Color pixelColor = mypic.GetPixel(i, z);

                textBox2.AppendText("  " + pixelColor.R + 
                    "     " + pixelColor.G + 
                    "     " + pixelColor.B + "     " + 
                    pixelColor.A + 
                    Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Image processing with lockbits, alternative to getpixel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168654/c-sharp-image-processing-with-lockbits-alternative-to-getpixel)

Comment: Also, calling `TextBox.AppendText` a few ten thousand times is slow. Use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Also, _"how we make a program like bar-code reader from image"_, don't reinvent the wheel: see [Recommend an Open Source .NET Barcode Reader Library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191192/recommend-an-open-source-net-barcode-reader-library).

Comment: what did you mean by "reinvent the wheel"?

Comment: See [Don't Reinvent The Wheel, Unless You Plan on Learning More About Wheels](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/02/dont-reinvent-the-wheel-unless-you-plan-on-learning-more-about-wheels.html).

Comment: codecaster ok i understand little.i will learn more...

Comment: It means: if your current assignment is to read barcodes from images and you currently don't know anything about images or barcodes, the quickest way to accomplish your goal is to use a (paid or free) third-party library that implements this. Alternatively, but that is usually only advisable when you are willing to understand all quirks of image recognition and barcode formats and you want to actually learn something from the exercise, then you can implement the whole shebang yourself, but it certainly will take more time while the results will at best be mediocre.

Comment: ­­­­­­­­­­yes i think i need to use a library

Comment: You know, when looping over an image's x and y, the logical loop variable names are really just 'x' and 'y', not 'i' and 'z'...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this:

```
var data = mypic.LockBits(
    new Rectangle(Point.Empty, mypic.Size),
    ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, mypic.PixelFormat);
var pixelSize = data.PixelFormat == PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb ? 4 : 3; // only works with 32 or 24 pixel-size bitmap!
var padding = data.Stride - (data.Width * pixelSize);
var bytes = new byte[data.Height * data.Stride];

// copy the bytes from bitmap to array
Marshal.Copy(data.Scan0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

var index = 0;
var builder = new StringBuilder();

for (var y = 0; y < data.Height; y++)
{
    for (var x = 0; x < data.Width; x++)
    {
        Color pixelColor = Color.FromArgb(
            pixelSize == 3 ? 255 : bytes[index + 3], // A component if present
            bytes[index + 2], // R component
            bytes[index + 1], // G component
            bytes[index]      // B component
            );

        builder
            .Append("  ")
            .Append(pixelColor.R)
            .Append("     ")
            .Append(pixelColor.G)
            .Append("     ")
            .Append(pixelColor.B)
            .Append("     ")
            .Append(pixelColor.A)
            .AppendLine();

        index += pixelSize;
    }

    index += padding;
}

// copy back the bytes from array to the bitmap
Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, data.Scan0, bytes.Length);

textBox2.Text = builder.ToString();
```

Is just an example, read some good tutorials about `LockBits` and imaging in general to understand clearly what happens.

Comment: Alessandro D'Andria    i'm glad for response.i will learn more about LOCKBITS.

Comment: i know the way i'm trying to do it is exactly wrong .i found artical http://www.mfranc.com/programming/operacje-na-bitmapkach-net-1/
thanks you

Comment: Please don't forget to unlock your locked bits. Also, the bytes array is unmodified; there's no reason at all to copy it back into the image.

Answer (score 1):

Getting pixel information shouldn't take that long. Can you log the time it takes `myimage()` to run? The slowness might be somewhere else. Also try removing the line that begins with `textBox2.AppendText` in `myimage()` and see how fast it runs then.

Comment: `GetPixel` takes indeed long execution times. Using `LockBits` is the way to do this.

Comment: I agree that ``LockBits`` is faster but in my experience, ``GetPixel`` doesn't take 20 minutes on a small image like that. What is he running this on? The original 4.77MHz IBM PC?

Comment: wait...exactly no my computer is (intel core 2 do ,4gb ram  )computer and i try it on my core i5 ASUS laptop computer but problem is same ..really happaning thing is it exute at least 20 minutes and also get not responding ..and i trying different images some are big .i used image 704 width-1400 height it get not responding on both lap and pc 
check if you don't agree .i uplorded it http://www.mediafire.com/?7etr90i4hqkoa2q

Comment: It was a joke. Did you try any of the things I suggested?