# Bitmap.GetPixel Keeps Giving Me An Error Message In C#

Tags: c#

```
    List<Bitmap> bitrecord = new List<Bitmap>();
    List<String> filerecord = new List<String>();
    string tempfilewrite = "";

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
    }

    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (Bitmap bitrecorder = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height))
        {
            using (Graphics recordgraphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitrecorder))
            {
                recordgraphics.CopyFromScreen(new Point(0, 0), Point.Empty, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size);
            }
            bitrecord.Add(bitrecorder);
        }
    }

    private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int z = 1; z < bitrecord.ToArray().Length; z++)
        {
            Bitmap bit = bitrecord[z];
            tempfilewrite = "" + z;
            for (int x = 1; x < Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 1; y < Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height; y++)
                {
                    tempfilewrite += ", (" + x + ", " + y + ", " + bit.GetPixel(x, y).R + ", " + bit.GetPixel(x, y).G + ", " + bit.GetPixel(x, y).B + ")";
                }
            }
            filerecord.Add(tempfilewrite);
        }
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Public\WriteLines.txt", filerecord);
        timer3.Stop();
    }
}
```

Above is code for a program that is supposed to take several pictures of your desktop and save them in a text file. However, when I start the program, it gives me an error with System.ArgumentException on the line where I am getting pixels with bit.GetPixel(x, y). If anyone knows how to fix this problem, that would be awesome, thanks.

Comment: When the exception is thrown, what are `x` and `y`?  Are they valid coordinates?

Comment: For each pixel I need to get the color, so X and Y are the X and Y values of the pixel in a specific bitmap that I am trying to save.

Comment: I know that.  That didn't answer the question I asked.  Literally, what are the values in `x` and `y`?

Comment: As far as I know, they are also valid coordinates.

Comment: What I'm guessing @Amy means is: What are the values of X and Y at the time the exception is thrown?

Comment: just a question, why are you initializing all for-loops from 1 instead of 0?

Comment: As far as you know?  Have you not checked that (x,y) is within the bounds of the image using a debugger?

Comment: You're looping over the bounds of `Screen.PrimaryScreen`, but you're trying to get the pixel from `bit`.  A valid coordinate for `Screen.PrimaryScreen` may not be valid for `bit` if `bit` is smaller.

Comment: and you're missing the first element [0] of the array

Comment: At the time the exception is thrown, the x and y values are both 1.

Comment: The bitmap should also be the same size as the screen size.

Comment: To expand what @amy said, you need to iterate the bounds of the bitmap you are working with just in case there's a difference cropping up there: `for (int x = 1; x < bit.Width; x++)` and `for (int y = 1; y < bit.Height; y++)`, that way `bit.GetPixel(x, y)` will always be in bounds.

Comment: Originally the x and y values were 0, but I was trying to resolve the issue myself and i changed those to 1.

Comment: @JacksonTarisa "should be" and "are" are not the same thing.  Check with the debugger.  Make sure.

Comment: If I change it to bit.Width and height, i get the same exception there

Comment: My values should work, its just the bit.GetPixel(x, y) thats throwing the error and i dont know why

Comment: Btw, calling `bit.GetPixel(x, y)` is relatively fairly slow. Calling it 3x per loop is even slower. You should look in to using [`bit.LockBits(`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168654/image-processing-with-lockbits-alternative-to-getpixel) instead.

Comment: check the size of bitrecorder or recordgraphics after CopyFromScreen has been executed.

Comment: timer2_Tick() creates a bitmap and immediately disposes it again.  Delete the *using* keyword, dispose only *old* bitmaps that you have processed.  Beware that you can easily run out of memory this way.

Comment: Looks like @HansPassant found the culprit!  Nice spot!

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: I dont know if its taking to long to write to the file, but the file where its supposed to show up in is not being written to.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain thanks I'll try that