# Parameter is not valid while trying to covnert byte array to image

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I have a program, which takes data from xlsx file and put them to dataGridView. Then I'm trying to convert this data(from dataGridView) to byte array for later place it to PictureBox, from Bitmap.
So I have datagridView(object) -> byte array - > Bitmap -> Picture.

And problem is occur, on the step, where I'm trin convert byte array to Image.

I've tried as many ways to fix it, as I could find in the Internet(especially modifications of MemoryStream and ImageConverter), but noone didn't help.  Debuger Says that data is ok(pic below). May be there is another way to convert it to image?

This is my dataGridView
[image: This is my dataGridView]

data from my array
[image: data from my array]

```
    private void buttonShowImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int size = (dataGridView1.RowCount) * (dataGridView1.ColumnCount-1);
        byte[] arrOfValues = new byte[size];
        PictureBox picBox = new PictureBox();


        int k = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1; j++)
            {
                arrOfValues[k++] = Convert.ToByte(dataGridView1[i, j].Value);
            }

        }

        ImageConverter ic = new ImageConverter();

        Image img = (Image)ic.ConvertFrom(arrOfValues);  // here is the problem 'data is not valid' 

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(img);

        picBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;

        picBox.Image = bmp;


        picBox.Show();

    }
```

Comment: It seems your links are not valid.

Comment: @SaeedBolhasani, what does it mean?

Comment: I can't see the links

Comment: Are you sure your byte array represents a valid Bitmap format, does it have the correct headers to represent a image?

Comment: @SaeedBolhasani it is a problem with your computer i see it on my machine.

Comment: try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173904/byte-array-to-image-conversion

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, no, I'm not sure. Actually, I thought that I need just an array of bytes and nothing special

Comment: @MaksSimple you may want to look in to just creating a blank bitmap of the size you need then setting the values in bulk via [Bitmap.LockBits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168654/image-processing-with-lockbits-alternative-to-getpixel) or with Bitmap.SetPixel if you are working with very small images and won't be frequently updating them.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain that was a problem, thank you!