# Creating Textures in Parallel

Tags: vb.net, parallel-processing, xna, monogame, texture2d

I'm working with alot of programmatically generated bitmaps that i need to convert to Texture2D so they can be displayed in Monogame

This is what i'm calling in a regular loop, the problem is that it's very slow.

```
Function BitmapToTexture2D(Bitmap As Drawing.Bitmap, Device As GraphicsDevice) As Texture2D
    Dim Result As Texture2D = Nothing
    Using MemoryStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream
        Bitmap.Save(MemoryStream, ImageFormat.Bmp)
        MemoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
        Result = Texture2D.FromStream(Device, MemoryStream)
    End Using

    Return Result
End Function
```

If i could create a Texture2D without needing to specify the GraphicsDevice that would be ideal.

**Update 1 :**
Trying to work around the problem i've tried to remove the need to go through a MemoryStream to hopefully improve performance.

```
Function BitmapToTexture2D(Bitmap As Drawing.Bitmap, Device As GraphicsDevice) As Texture2D
    Dim Result As New Texture2D(Device, Bitmap.Size.Width, Bitmap.Size.Height)
    Result.SetData(BitmapToColorArrayMonogame(Bitmap))

    Return Result
End Function

Function BitmapToColorArrayMonogame(Bitmap As Drawing.Bitmap) As Color()
    Dim Color() As Color = New Color(Bitmap.Size.Width * Bitmap.Size.Height - 1) {}

    For X As Integer = 0 To (Bitmap.Size.Width - 1)
        For Y As Integer = 0 To (Bitmap.Size.Height - 1)
            Color((Bitmap.Size.Width * Y) + X) = SystemColorToMonogame(Bitmap.GetPixel(X, Y))
        Next
    Next
    Return Color
End Function

Function SystemColorToMonogame(Color As System.Drawing.Color) As Color
    Return New Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color(Color.R, Color.G, Color.B, Color.A)
End Function
```

The results :

- Non-MemoryStream : 4659
- MemoryStream : 252

in Milliseconds.

MemoryStream is significantly faster than working around it.
Still i would prefer if i could just do this in the background, in parallel.

**Update 2 :**
[With code adapted from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168654/image-processing-with-lockbits-alternative-to-getpixel)

```
Function BitmapToTexture2DLockBits(Bitmap As Drawing.Bitmap, Device As GraphicsDevice) As Texture2D
    Dim Result As New Texture2D(Device, Bitmap.Size.Width, Bitmap.Size.Height)
    Dim Rectangle As New Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, Bitmap.Width, Bitmap.Height)
    Dim Data As BitmapData = Bitmap.LockBits(Rectangle, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, Bitmap.PixelFormat)
    Dim NumBytes As Integer = (Data.Stride * Bitmap.Height)
    Dim Bytes As Byte() = New Byte(NumBytes - 1) {}
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(Data.Scan0, bytes, 0, numBytes)
    Bitmap.UnlockBits(data)
    Result.SetData(Bytes)

    Return Result
End Function
```

The results :

- SetData From Array : 4371
- MemoryStream : 221
- LockBits : 63

Significantly faster, however still not in parallel. It cannot be in parallel because GraphicsDevice has to be used to create the Texture2D and if called in parallel it will lock up the entire application.

There has to be some way to create a Texture2D without needing the GraphicsDevice.

Note : Further testing shows that you cannot SetData on a texture in parallel either, it locks up and the parallel loop never finishes.

Comment: Have you tried using SetData instead of FromStream? You could convert your stream to an array and pass it to SetData

Comment: @the_lotus Yes, the problem with that is that you can't SetData without initializing the Texture2D first, which also requires the GraphicsDevice.

Comment: I don't know anything about MonoGame, but I don't think it's the graphics device that's causing this to run slow. Rather, I'd say it's the saving of the bitmap into a memory stream that's causing the bottleneck. GDI+ isn't exactly known to be fast...

Comment: @Visual Vincent I updated the question, not using MemoryStream was much slower.

Comment: I didn't say it was the memory stream that was causing the bottleneck, I said it was _the saving of the bitmap_ into it. GDI+ in its entirety is very slow, and `GetPixel()`/`SetPixel()` are two of the slowest methods you can use. Everything in the `System.Drawing` namespace belongs to GDI+, and all methods that deal with graphics are much slower than what they should be.

Comment: The fastest way to get a bitmap's pixel data is to use the [**`Bitmap.LockBits()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d(v=vs.110).aspx) technique. It is a bit tricky to get it right, and I don't know if it'll be faster than using a memory stream, but I'll see if I can write you an example later today. Anyhow, to achieve parallelism look into [**`Parallel.For()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Visual Vincent I updated the question again. Parallel.for won't work when we need the GraphicsDevice to create the Texture2D.

Comment: Why not? If you use a [**lambda expression**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/lambda-expressions) (assuming it's supported) you can use any variable directly inside it.

Comment: @Visual Vincent I'm not sure i understand what you mean, GraphicsDevice has to be specified to create a new Texture2D and it doesn't allow itself to be used in parallel.
Could you supply an example of what you mean?

Comment: Oh, so it throws an exception if used in a background thread? Didn't know that... Then I don't think there's very much you can do. My guess is that the graphics device is necessary as it is the pipeline to the GPU. The textures are stored in the VRAM, so you need something that can copy them there.

Comment: @Visual Vincent Not entirely, it just locks up the loop and never finishes, without any error messages popping up.